# Custom Field Suite repeater doesn't work with Timber plugin

Tags: custom-fields, timber

I have a problem with repeater fields in CFS, namely I am not able to display the content in the template in any way. I follow the documentation of TIMBER, Custom Field Suite and I even read about Advanced Fields, unfortunately it didn't help.

I created a custom field and in the template I added:

```
{% for field in post.meta('knowFields') %}
    <article class="content-box">
        <figure class="content-box__ico">
            <img src="{{ field.fieldIco }}" alt="" class="content-box__ico--gfx">
        </figure>
        <p class="content-box--desc">{{ field.fieldDesc }}</p>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

I also set the variable this way:

```
{% set fields = post.meta('knowFields') %}
{% for field in fields %}
    <article class="content-box">
        <figure class="content-box__ico">
            <img src="{{ field.fieldIco }}" alt="" class="content-box__ico--gfx">
        </figure>
        <p class="content-box--desc">{{ field.fieldDesc }}</p>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, nothing works. Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all inside src tag syntax should be `{{Image(field.fieldIco).src}}`
secondly, you can use `{{dump(field)}}` and see what type of data you are getting.